# Where does property when added to function object

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

```
function foo()
{
       var a=5;
 }
```

Since above function is JavaScript object so we can add properties to it like `foo.p=6`.But while doing `console.log(foo)` i am not able to see the `p` property of object but is accessible through `foo.p` and foo['p'].

Also i am not able to access `foo.a` if we consider foo as JavaScript object.

Answer (score 2):

Try `console.dir(foo);` instead, which lists the properties of the object. `concole.log` simply outputs some representation of the value, the browser thinks would be useful.

`foo.a` can't work. `a` is a **local** variable, not a property, and only exist while `foo` is executed.

Comment: Have a look at the last sentence.

Comment: Wow >_> So the last sentence is a completely separate question. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

When logging an object, the browser will choose how to render it in the console. This may be as primitive as calling `.toString()` on it, or as complex as giving you the ability to navigate its properties.

Furthermore, the console is not a standard. Browsers may implement it however they like, although for convenience they will keep to a common style. Ultimately, however, this means they will be different.

Internet Explorer:
[image: IE]

Google Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Notice how I had to use `console.dir()` to force Chrome to give me a navigable view of the object, rather than its simple `.toString()` representation.

Answer (score 0):

"a" is a local variable, this not accessible from outside the function.

you'd like something like this:

```
var myClass = function(){
this.foo = 'bar';
}

var myInstance = myClass();
myInstance.foo // 'bar'
```

or as a plain object:

```
var myObj = {
foo: 'bar'
}

myObj.foo // 'bar'
myObj.foo = 123;
myObj.foo // 123
```

Comment: `a` is not equal to `p`. Please read the question more attentively ;)

Comment: but p is not a variable inside his foo() function.

Comment: Correct. OP is trying to set a property on the function object, and is asking why it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of achieving that. One is using objects in Javascript and another one with the called "Module Pattern".
For using objects, you can do:

```
function MyObject() {
  this.foo = "myObj";
}
var mo = new MyObject();
console.log(mo.foo); //Will print "myObj".
```

Module pattern works as below:

```
var MP = (function(){}(
  var foo = "MP";
  return {
    foo : foo
  }

));
console.log(MP.foo); // Will print "MP"
```

Comment: This is not the question that was being asked. Good answer, but off-topic ;)